# Change row color when a cell changes date

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to change a row colour when an exact date is specified in a cell.

I've tried using conditional formatting, stating the range of the cells (A2:M2) that need to be highlighted green should a specific date be selected in a cell (L2). All that is happening, though, is the cell that contains the date is being highlighted rather than the entire row.

The overall intention is for an entire row to be highlighted a different color when a specific date is selected (L2). The same logic will be applied to all cells below L2.

[Example Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J4jTnAtEpmgMiRCxSI7R6uoUvUDI3bO6suRHfASG4Pw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J4jTnAtEpmgMiRCxSI7R6uoUvUDI3bO6suRHfASG4Pw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
Apply to Range
A2:M2
Custom forumla is:
=L2=L2

Answer (score 0):

Use "$" in your conditional formatting custom formula: 
*Apply to range* A2:M2
*Custom formula is* =$L2=$L$2